# CakePHP without mod_rewrite problems

Tags: mysql, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I've developed a website using CakePHP and I am now trying to host it on the live server. I couln't get much help from the hosting service, but I *think* they do not allow mod_rewrite (I get  500 server error whenever I try to turn it on).

So, I looked into using CakePHP without mod_rewrite. Now I can at least see the website, but I'm getting tons of errors, in particular:

- The css and js files are not found.
- There seems to be problems with the database, although it might be related to the problem above, I can't tell for sure.

The live website can be seen at [new.enviro.lu](http://new.enviro.lu).
The working website can be seen at [enviro.webforall.be](http://enviro.webforall.be)

Can anybody point me into the right direction to solve these problems?

I'm using CakePHP 1.3.4.

Comment: The 500 error suggests that the .htaccess file was invalid, not that mod_rewrite was disabled (unless you didn't wrap the instructions in ifmodule conditionals). The database errors are not related to mod_rewrite.

Comment: While testing, just setting RewriteEngine to on gives the 500 error. If set to off, there was no error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the CSS and JavaScript pages not showing is that you have Apache's DocumentRoot point to the wrong directory. The DocumentRoot [should be](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/914/Production) /app/webroot, but you have it set to Cake's root directory. You can see that the paths work if you access http://new.enviro.lu/app/webroot/.

The database error on the page is:

> Error: Database table content_pages for model ContentPage was not found.

This suggests that either the `content_pages` table has not been created as the error message says or the database configuration points at a wrong database.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Where can I set the DocumentRoot? Also, take a look at the SQL queries at the bottom... They look truncated, is that normal?

Comment: You were right about the configuration of the database, it was wrong. Correcting it solved the SQL queries problem. I couldn't find where to put the DocumentRoot setting, so I pointed the sub-domain to the /app/webroot directory instead. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Try contacting your hosting provider and ask them to turn mod_rewrite **on** for your account, or ask them how you can do it. CakePhp will not work without it.

Comment: From the docs: *"mod_rewrite is preferred, but by no means required"*.

Comment: well that was new to me... +1 for you, and I apologize for the disinformation. Can I delete this?